# I've written the python code to import excel file (multiple sheets) into my sql server, But for large file it taking too much time

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to import large excel files with multiple sheets into my sql server but the problem is that it taking too much time, is there any way i can make it efficient or do it in a better way.I'm kinda new to this language so any help can be grateful.Here is my code:

```
#taking file input and reading it 
                
        
        filename = input("Input the Filename: ")
                dfs = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None)
     #my main function 
        d = {k: v[['SR_NO', 'NTN']].values.tolist()
                    for k, v in  pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None).items()
                    }
            for k, v in dfs.items():
                cols = ['SR_NO', 'NTN']
                dfs = pd.read_excel(filename, usecols=cols, sheet_name=None)
                records = pd.concat(df for df in dfs.values()).to_numpy().tolist()
                d[k] = records
                
     #for test sheetnames  
          print (d.keys())
                
     #cursor connection to insert records
             try:
                    cursor = conn.cursor()
                    cursor.executemany(sql_insert, records)
                    cursor.commit();
                except Exception as e:
                    cursor.rollback()
                    print(str(e[1]))
                finally:
                    print('Task is complete.')
                    cursor.close()
                    conn.close()
```

Comment: You are reading each Excel file over and over and over!  You read it once at the top, then again in your list comprehension, and then again and again in the loop.  For gosh sakes, don't do that!!  Read each file once, then use the dfs you get.  Since your indentation is messed up, I can't tell what you're really trying to.  Fix the source, then we'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your intent, but I suspect all you need is this.  Read the file ONCE.  And the `for` loop is already enumerating through the dfs values, so you don't need another loop inside.  And you don't need `concat`, if you only have one thing.

```
filename = input("Input the Filename: ")
dfs = pd.read_excel(filename, usecols=['SR_NO','NTN'], sheet_name=None)

d = {}
for k, v in dfs.items():
    d[k] = v.to_numpy().tolist()
    
print (d.keys())
```

Comment: Thankyou for helping out, i have removed internal loops and concat let me test it now

Comment: So now the problem is that it giving me output: dict_keys(['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'Sheet4', 'Sheet5', 'Sheet6'])
Task is complete.

Comment: Reading all the sheets but writing only 1 sheet into my database

Comment: So here is the possible solution, i've edited your version of code i.e:
d[k] = pd.concat(dfs.values()).to_numpy().tolist() , 
By doing this it can also write all the sheets into my database